# Add objects from one layer to another at QGIS

Tags: qgis

How can I add some objects from one layer to another one.
I mean, I have one layer with specific data(e.gg polyline)
at the same time I have another layer with different objects .how can I copy/move object between the layers.
Thanks
Hamid

Answer (score 16):

If you'll follow the screenshots below you'll be able to copy / cut features from one layer and to paste / move them to another layer:

This is how the first layer looks:

[image]

And this is the second:

[image]

Going back to the first layer and selecting some features:

[image]

[image]

Select `Copy` or `Cut` from the `Edit` menu if you want to duplicate or move existing features into another layer:

[image]

Select the other layer:

[image]

Perform the paste operation:

[image]

Here's the expected result (the features from the first layers are duplicated or moved into the second layer):

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the target layer has the attribute fields you want to preserve for the copied objects.

Comment: I appreciate you thatnk this is what I wanted

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. Remember that the layer you want to paste into must be toggled for editing. (Took me a couple of goes to work that out!).