# Connect two Shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, grass-gis

I have two shapefiles which should be connected to one single shapefile without a gap, unfortunately there is a gap between them:
[image]

I tried to use `v.clean`in Grass GIS but because of the shape of the two lines, it was not possible to connect only the wanted area:

[image]

Does someone has an idea how to solve this problem? I also tried SpatiaLite in QGIS which also didn't work well.

Comment: It should be simple enough to edit one of the features or digitize a new feature to connect them. If this doesn't work for your situation please [edit] your question with enough information to fully understand your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get both lines into the same shapefile first (there are multiple ways of doing this, e.g., using [copy and paste](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90119/add-objects-from-one-layer-to-another-at-qgis) or the [merge tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280162/merge-shapefiles-in-qgis-3-0-0-desktop)).
You then can use a Plugin such as [Join multiple lines](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/joinmultiplelines/) to join them together automatically.